# trouble proofing with full induction

Tags: solution-verification, induction

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(1+ \frac{1}{k}\right)^k = \frac{n^{n}}{n!}  \text{ for n element } N \geq 2$$

$n = 2$ is true for both

$$\prod_{k=1}^{(n+1)-1} \left(1+ \frac{1}{k}\right)^k = \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

simplified:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n -1} \left(1+ \frac{1}{k}\right)^k  * \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n= \frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n!}$$

Induction requirement instead of product mark:

$$\frac{n^{n}}{n!}  * \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n= \frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n!}$$

afterwards I just can't find the solution.
It would be awesome If someone could help me.

I always come to:

$$\frac{n^n + 1}{n!} \neq \frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}$$

Comment: in the third line you put a $+$ instead of a $*$

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. I edited the typo.

Comment: Simple induction is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you increment $n$ to $n+1$, the LHS gets multiplied by

$$1+\frac1n$$ and the RHS by

$$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\frac{n+1}{n+1}.$$

Hence the claim is wrong (but the fix easy).

Comment: Hey Sorry I still had some typos in the equation. Now it should behave differently. My task is to prove that the term is valid

Comment: @cycy1234: if you look carefully, you will get the correct answer.